# Using Webpack to only generate a vendor bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, webpack, bower

Currently, we use Bower for the front-end dependencies of our `AngularJS` project and the `bower-concat` Grunt task to compile our `bower_components` into a `libraries.js` file. In a similar manner, we bundle the library CSS files into a `libraries.css`.

Looking towards the future, we want to switch to using `NPM` and `Webpack`. Preferably, we'd initially like to use Webpack to only create a vendor bundle, which would then replace our libraries.js file. We'd also like to use Webpack to bundle our vendor CSS files. For the time being, we'd like to keep on using Grunt's regular concat task for out application logic and CSS. Essentially, we wish to touch as little application code as possible in this switch.

I've attempted to do this by moving all my dependencies from `bower.json` to `package.json` and fixing the version numbers and package names where needed, and then creating an `index.j`s file in which I import all the dependencies.

My webpack.config.js currently looks as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/app/js')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\/.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
    }
};
```

This code does create both a `main.bundle.js` and a `main~vendor.bundle.js` file, but including the files in our HTML template and booting up the application immediately leads to an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Googling the issue returns few results, since all posts on the subject assume a complete switch to Webpack.

Ultimately, my question boils down to 'Can you use Webpack to create ONLY a vendor bundle, which can then be included in a `Thymeleaf-style` HTML file and if so, how?'

Comment: So when you open the main-vendor.bundle.js file - is there angular included?

Comment: @madflow There is, yes. I ran the webpack config unminified to check. Even using the expose-loader or the ProvidePlugin doesn't seem to get things recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test:

```
//index.js
import angular from 'angular';
import angularAnimate from 'angular-animate';
import uirouter from '@uirouter/angularjs';
```

```
//src/main/webapp/app/js/app.js
angular
  .module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate'])
  .component('com', { template: 'hello' });
```

```
<!-- src/main/webapp/app/index.html -->
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="js/main.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendors~main.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(angular.version);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <com></com>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

> Object { full: "1.7.8", major: 1, minor: 7, dot: 8, codeName: "enthusiastic-oblation" }

And the comonent yields 'hello'.

So - are you doing something different?

Comment: I mainly had a different way of importing in index.js:
```
import 'angular';
//other imports
```

Doing it this way seems to yield some improvement, in that now the problem seems to be that Highcharts isn't working. At least it's not saying that angular is undefined anymore, so thank you for that suggestion!